# Naturality of product functor morphisms

Tags: category-theory

In https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/LN.pdf

On page 10, equations (13) and (14)
it seems to me that outl on the left of the equations is not the same outl as on the right (likewise for outr).

I believe the outl on the left goes from some object AxB to A, while the outl on the right goes from A’xB’ to A’, where k1 goes from A to A’. So, the equations maybe should have been written

k1 . outl = outl’ . (k1xk2)

I am traveling and on a phone so please forgive the lack of a diagram. If anyone can confirm that the two appearances of outl (and similarly outr) are actually not (necessarily) the same morphism, that would be great. I interjected necessarily since the diagram should still make sense if k1: A->A and k2: B->B, but I believe the purpose of the equations was for general k1: A->A’ and k2: B->B’.

Thank you.

Comment: You might have better luck over on the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/category-theory)

Comment: Or over on [cs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. `outl` and `outr` are natural transformations, and here the writers abuse notation to use them as arrows, while instead they should be specific components at the right types.

This confusion probably comes from how this is implemented in functional programming languages like Haskell, where `outl :: (a, b) -> a` is regular function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the confirmation and the extra explanation. I really appreciate it. I also posted over on the math board as the gentlemen above suggested. I’m sorry to say they were not so kind and didn’t really answer it over there. I’m happy to see the programming side has excellent people. Thanks again.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `outl` in Haskell is a polymorphic function, so it's a natural transformation (naturality follows from parametricity).

Comment: Sjoerd and Bartosz mention nat trans.  Products are limits from 2->C.  As limits, outl and outr are legs of the limit cones, and, therefore, components of nat trans at some type, and outl and outr are coordinated with one another in the limit definition.  However, the Haskel outl::(a,b)->a doesn't look like a limit, and doesn't seem coordinated with outr.  Instead outl and outr look like two independent nat trans between functors from CxC->C. Which specific nat trans are you referring to and what ensures coherence between outl and outr if they are defined independently?

Comment: @docjosh The CxC->C ones. Haskell is not a proof checking language and knows nothing about limits so there's no strict insurance that the implementations of `outl` and `outr` are correct, you'd have to check that manually. (Although thanks to the type checker there can only be one implementation of each.)

Comment: @sjoerd_visscher Thank you again for the answer. Would I be correct stating that parametricity implies naturality of outl, and then, _independently_, parametricity implies naturality of outr, but then by magic (or maybe by Wadler's Thms for Free?) it must be the case that (given type-checked implementations of outl and outr) we get the product universal construction.  This is even more than parametricity giving naturality.  It's also creating some additional coherence where I am forced to write _both_ outl/outr "correctly".  Is this intuition sensible?